# Multi-language support in API.AI

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an existing Dialogflow agent, but now want to add a new language. I have figured out how to add new intents for other languages in the GUI, but its not clear how the fulfillment logic needs to change for each language.

How do I use the locale information to respond for each language intent?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a language, there will be another pill shape under your bots name... Mine started in English (en), and I added Spanish (es). First, I do my thing in english:

[image]

Then, I click the (es) pill and add examples and responses there:

[image]